# What does "set change" mean? And how is it different from the plain word "change"

Tags: meaning

For example, "a degree can be defined as a 'set change' in temperature measured against a given scale"

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(temperature)

Comment: I doubt *set* is necessary.  It has been in the article for [almost a decade](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Degree_(temperature)&diff=prev&oldid=428948786), which suggests that it may be unobjectionable, and I suspect the original intention was to suggest that the amount represented by a change of one degree is set by the scale being used.

Comment: I believe it's "set" as a past participle, meaning "fixed" - i.e. the size of the change is always the same (for a given scale).

Comment: I think the "set" there specifies that a degree is a *particular, specific amount* of change on a given scale.  It's not enough to say that a degree centigrade is "a fraction of the total temperature change from freezing to boiling", it is specifically 1% of that total temperature change.

Comment: I agree with @psmears. The past participle "set" is being used adjectivally to describe "change" as being fixed, a predetermined amount of temperature change used to establish a universal unit of temperature change that is always the same in reference to a given scale (e.g.,  Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin).

Comment: *set* is a necessary part of the definition. Comments about the definition are sound and deserve to be worked into an answer. I leave it to one of the commentators to do so.

Comment: @psmears I actually looked this up and "set" has an adjective form which means "fixed or arranged in advance", hence I think it's not "set" as a past participle being used adjectivally but the adjective for of set being used to mean that.

Comment: @ShahzadRahim: The adjective derives from the participle, and is more or less identical in meaning - I'm not sure you can really say definitively that it's one or the other in this case :)

Comment: @psmears Except I can't find the definition "fixed or arranged in advance" when I look at the definition of the verb form of the word set, (if you google "define set"), if you could share a source where it has the same definition, I would appreciate it. Enlighten me if you think I'm missing something.

Comment: @ShahzadRahim: "set" is probably the English word with the most meanings! For instance, [this dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set) lists over 30. And the meanings overlap, so different dictionaries will divide them up differently. If you look at meanings 4, 10 and 18c in that listing, those are the ones that match this usage most closely.